# Too many decimals on the labels with geom_text_contour in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to graph multiple data sets in ggplot using `geom_contour_fill` by adding labels with `geom_text_contour` and, sometimes, tags with several decimals are generated.

For example for this [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novvier/sampleData/master/dataint.csv):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)
df <- read.csv("dataint.csv")
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
    geom_contour_fill() +
    geom_text_contour(check_overlap = TRUE, stroke = 0.1, size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider defining breaks at round numbers and using those for both layers:

```
breaks = seq(16, 20, by = 0.4)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  geom_contour_fill(breaks = breaks) +
  geom_text_contour(breaks = breaks,
                    check_overlap = TRUE, stroke = 0.1, size = 3)
```

[image]